# while changing permalink, page redirected you too many times

Tags: permalinks

while changing permalink from plain to any other. every pages in the site shows "domainname.com redirected you too many times"...
home page working perfectly.

Please give a solution for this problem.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache, checking with an Incognito window, or using a HTTP Header Check service? Browsers cache redirects, so it could be that you were just experiencing a cached version and the site was working with the updated permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the website URL settings? There might be something wrong in the configuration. Follow these steps:

1. Head to **Settings > General Settings**.
2. Make sure that **WordPress Address(URL)** and **Site Address(URL)**
   are the same.

If you don't have access to the wp-admin area, you can update the URLs using the wp-config.php file. You can find the details [right here](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-fix-too-many-redirects-issue-for-a-wordpress-website/).

Also, the problem might have caused to the problematic plugins. You can try disabling all the plugins and activate one by one to find the defective one.